# How to solve the equation without rearranging it in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, equation-solving

Just want to ask if I have an equation `$cost = (($q * 5)/$z - $x) * $q *2.32 + 0.34`
If `$cost, $z and $x`have the actual value, is there any method to calculate `$q` without rearranging the eqaution?
Or How to get the new function of `$q` in terms of the `$cost`?

Comment: You want the equation for `$q`? That would be a different equation, and by definition you need to rearrange this one. Have I misunderstood what you're asking?

Comment: Sounds like you need to review your algebra.

Comment: @ST8Z6FR57ABE6A8RE9UF To solve this equation, yes, normally we do need to rearrange the equation. But I just want to know if there is any method to solve the equation without rearranging it. Sometimes it will be difficult to rearrange a very complex equation manually.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Well, if there is a method to automatically look for the solution, it will save a lot of time when you have more than 100 eqautions to solve.

Comment: Sometimes you need to use the right tool for the right job.   I suggest Wolfram Alpha to solve these types of problems.  https://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: @Knox Thanks for the tool. I am just curious if there is any function could do the same work.

Comment: possibler with dichotomie method i think